# Classifying video with variable frames num

Tags: python, video, pytorch, classification, image-classification

I have the object coordinates for each frame from the video, taken in 1s increments.

It's actually a simple **.csv** table:

`video_name | frame_num | x | y | z | target`

I try to classify this data with pytorch (LSTM). But I ran into problems that each video has a different number of frames. This is an example:

```
(frames_num, number_of_points_for_ech_frame, coordinates)

(137, 20, 3)
(6, 20, 3)
(22, 20, 3)
(71, 20, 3)
(6, 20, 3)
(183, 20, 3)
```

P.s. there is no original videos.

Is there any way to classify on a different number of frames from the video using PyTorch? Without bringing the number of frames to the same number.

Maybe some models or data preparation techniques for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways around this, if you don't want to pad the frames to the same length:

- Use a batch size of 1. This will take longer to train and be less efficient, but is probably the easiest option.
- Use the [`pack_sequence()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_sequence.html) and [`unpack_sequence()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.unpack_sequence.html) functions with your LSTM:

```py
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_sequence, unpack_sequence

# train_data is list of frames of shape (frames_num, number_of_points_for_ech_frame, coordinates)
packed = pack_sequence(train_data, enforce_sorted=False)

# ...
output_packed, h, c = lstm(packed)
outputs = unpack_sequence(output_packed)
```